# Eclipse won't start after uninstalling EGit plugin

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I just uninstalled all of EGit plugins that I had before.  The uninstall went through smoothly and asked me to restart Eclipse at the end but then Eclipse wouldn't start giving me the following error message:

[image]

I get that when I try to launch Eclipse from my shortcut on the Start Menu (using Win 7).  But when I go to the Eclipse install directory itself and hit eclipse.exe there, I get the following error message:

[image]

I did go to see whether there is jvm.dll in the above directory and indeed it is there.

Any idea how to fix it?

**UPDATE 1:**  I reinstalled both Eclipse **AND** JRE but the problem remains.

**UPDATE 2:**  Here are the contents of my `eclipse.ini`

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Comment: have you checked if the paths that Eclipse reclaims exist?

Comment: @CharlesB, no, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

JRE & Eclipse should both be the same bit version (32 or 64). Your screenshot suggests you're running the 32-bit version of JRE, but I don't know if that was before or after you re-installed. `java -version` should help with JRE. Your eclipse.ini file will tell you the Eclipse bit version you're running. For example:

plugins/org.eclipse.enter code hereequinox.launcher.win32.win32.**x86**_1.0.

You should confirm this and try manually pointing Eclipse to your JRE binary. Here's a [Windows example](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value%3a_Windows_Example)

```
-vm c:\java\jdk\1.6\bin\javaw.exe
```

If that works, you just need to update your eclipse.ini with the correct path.

Good luck.

Comment: I updated the OP with the contents of my eclipse.ini.  Thanks

Comment: Two things you can try: Remove the first 02 lines from your .ini file and try relaunching. That might work.
`-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar`

Several folks registered the same issue on bugs.eclipse.org, and it seems to be a problem with unzipping the download. You can try installing Eclipse classic, or try reinstalling the same version, but unzip the file with [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) instead.

Comment: Did you try re-downloading and unzipping with 7zip before reinstalling?

Comment: no, i am at work, very strict network, don't allow free sftwr downloads...  but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the Java I had (and the only version I had access to due to the corporate network restrictions) was 1.6 32-bit even though my laptop is 64-bit (why does this work?).  When I tried to reinstall Eclipse, I was using the 64-bit version.  It worked when I installed the 32-bit version.  BTW, the Eclipse version is

`Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers   1.4.1.20110909-1818 epp.package.jee null`